# If $X\sim X^{-1}$ does $\text{Var}(X)=0?$

Tags: probability

Just a quick question. I have been reading about inverse distributions and wondered whether this might be the case. Is it true?

Comment: I wonder why you wonder that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. For example, $\Bbb P(X=2)=\Bbb P(X=\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alaternative to user104254's example, consider $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$, which not only has $X\sim X^{-1}$ but also has has $X=X^{-1}$ with probability $1$.